Spatie Translatable - Checkbox list
I am developing a project with Laravel Filament. I am using the "Laravel-translatable" Package in the project.
I am saving the data in English and Spanish.
The data I saved in the database is shown below.
In another section, when I want to show the data I saved before (when I want to show the data I saved with "CheckboxList"), the package names are not visible. I would like to get information from you about this.
database record column
The second and third images are the section where I save the packages. There are English and Spanish versions. I don't have any problems here.
package
package
A separate area where I want to show the packages. When I list here with "CheckboxList", the package names do not appear. When I do not use the "Laravel-translatable" package, I do not have any problems.
enter image description here
Thanks everyone
I tried many ways but did not succeed.
